# What is wrong with this proof of Wedderburn's little theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, fake-proofs

**Wedderburn's little theorem** $\quad$ every finite domain $A$ is a field.

**Proof** $\quad$ Let $x$ be a nonzero element of $A$. Because $A$ is finite, there
  exist positive integers $n$, $k$ such that $x^n = x^{n + k}$. It is easy to
  see by induction that the set $E = \left \{x^i : i \in \mathbf{N}^*\right\}$
  does not contain $0$; it follows therefore from $x^n\left(1 - x^k\right) = 0$
  that $x^k = 1$. Thus, $x^{k - 1}$ is the inverse of $x$ (when $k = 1$, $x$ has
  inverse $1$).

All the proofs I have seen of this result are much more sophisticated than mine. Hence, I am doubting its correctness and could use a second opinion.

Comment: Your proof only shows that every *commutative* domain is a field. Wedderburn's theorem states moreover that your $A$ is commutative.

Comment: @martini: You could turn that comment into an answer so the question can be marked resolved.

Comment: I think the word "domain" is ambiguous. It should be called "not necessarily commutative domain" though it's awkward.

Comment: The existence of inverses can also be proved by considering the map $y \mapsto xy$ and arguing that it is injective and hence surjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wedderburn's little theorem states as you wrote above, that a finite domain is a field. A field is a *commutative* domain $A$, such that every nonzero $x \in A$ has a multiplicative inverse. Your proof only shows that any finite domain is a skew field. You must also prove that $A$ is commutative, which needs more sophisticated arguments.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I keep thinking that "field" is the translation for "corps" (French), which are not assumed to be commutative. Thank you.

Comment: @user25784 Indeed I believe Fields were originally not assumed to be commutative, especially by french mathematicians. Andre Weil's number theory text follows that convention.